# PHP MD5 equivalent to Java

Tags: java, php, md5

I need a PHP equivalent for Java's MD5 functionality which takes a byte array and return the hash as a 16 byte array back. **I'm not need an Java equivalent for the PHP's md5 function.** The problem is that the PHP's `md5` function takes only strings, not byte arrays.

Heres is the expected result in Java:

```
// input byte array
// for short: 123456
final byte[] data = new byte[] { (byte) 0x12, (byte) 0x34, (byte) 0x56 };

// expected 16 hash bytes
// for short: ae1fa6209a246b8b2f2cd2d21be8f2e1
final byte[] expectedHash = new byte[] {
        (byte) 0xae, (byte) 0x1f, (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0x20,
        (byte) 0x9a, (byte) 0x24, (byte) 0x6b, (byte) 0x8b,
        (byte) 0x2f, (byte) 0x2c, (byte) 0xd2, (byte) 0xd2,
        (byte) 0x1b, (byte) 0xe8, (byte) 0xf2, (byte) 0xe1 };
```

My try in PHP is:

```
<?php
// input byte array
$data = array(0x12, 0x34, 0x56);

// pack data in a string, becouse md5 can only
// compute a hash for a string
$dataString = pack('C*', $data); // is it the right way?
var_dump($dataString);

// compute the hash and get a string back
$hash = md5($dataString, true);

// expected 16 hash bytes
// for short: ae1fa6209a246b8b2f2cd2d21be8f2e1
$expected = array(
    0xae, 0x1f, 0xa6, 0x20,
    0x9a, 0x24, 0x6b, 0x8b,
    0x2f, 0x2c, 0xd2, 0xd2,
    0x1b, 0xe8, 0xf2, 0xe1);
var_dump($expected);

// convert the string back to a byte array
$actual = unpack('C*', $hash); // is it the right way?
var_dump($actual);

assert($expected == $actual);
?>
```

`$dataString` has the length of 0. So the first error must be in `pack`. But I don't know how to pack an arbitrary byte array into a string. Can you give me the right `format` argument for that?

Comment: Have you tried using `implode`?

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for hint, but implode doesn't return the right string: `implode('', array(12, 34, 56))` returns `123456`. It only converts integer values to decimal representation and concatinates there.

Comment: You do realize that in PHP, "\x12" is a byte, meaning exactly the same thing as Java's 0x12, don't you ? Therefore, "\x12\x34\x56" is a byte array, and it is also a string.

Comment: @SirDarius: Whats the interpretation of `'\x12\x34\x56'`? A ascii string with 3 chars, a utf8 string with 1 1/2 char etc.? The different between an explicit byte array and a string is that I can get and set a byte at any position. I don't know if it's possible for a string to get and set a byte (interpreted as a char) at the same position becouse the different char encodings.

Comment: There is no interpretation, as long as you don't actually use string functions that expect a given encoding. PHP strings can contain binary data. Right from http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php: "A string is series of characters, where a character is the same as a byte." Period, there's nothing more to it.

Comment: @SirDarius: Ah, ok, character == byte. Thats not very intuitive for me. For example in Haskell is a string an array of characters not an array of bytes, thats clear but in PHP, muhaha :) So if I undestand it right, `strlen` returns the number of bytes not the number of characters. And `$myString[$n]` should return the n-th byte not the n-th character.

Comment: Exactly, strlen() returns the number of bytes, the `[]` operator works on bytes too. If you ever wanted to count characters for a given encoding, you have to use mb_strlen instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it :)

```
<?php
function javaMd5($data) {
    assert(is_array($data));

    $dataString = byteArrayToString($data);

    $hashString = md5($dataString, true);
    assert(strlen($hashString) == 16);

    $hash = stringToByteArray($hashString);

    assert(count($hash) == 16);
    return $hash;
}

function stringToByteArray($s) {
    assert(is_string($s));

    $result = array_fill(0, strlen($s), 0);
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($s); $i++) {
        $result[$i] = ord($s[$i]);
    }
    return $result;
}

function byteArrayToString($b) {
    assert(is_array($b));

    $asciiString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($b); $i++) {
        assert($b[$i] >= 0 && $b[$i] <= 255);
        $asciiString .= chr($b[$i]);
    }

    $utf8String = utf8_encode($asciiString);

    return $utf8String;
}

$data = array(0x12, 0x34, 0x56);

$expected = array(
    0xae, 0x1f, 0xa6, 0x20,
    0x9a, 0x24, 0x6b, 0x8b,
    0x2f, 0x2c, 0xd2, 0xd2,
    0x1b, 0xe8, 0xf2, 0xe1);

$actual = javaMd5($data);

assert($expected == $actual);
?>
```

I'am not sure about string encoding but it works. I don't have an explinations for that PHP uses a implicit xyz-encoded string instead of an explizit byte array like Java does. The manuel doesn't say everithing about char encoding. Thats might be the reason for that there are so many questions about how to calculate the md5 of a string aquivalent to PHP in the language XYZ.